# How to find a String that has specific starting and ending characters and contains a newline character

Tags: regex

How would i create a regular expression to find new line characters inside jstl arguments?
I did some research and found that the following will give me all the JSTL tags by finding everything btween '${' and '}'.  But i haven't been able to figure out how to change that to find just jstl arguments that contain '\r\n'.

```
(\$\{)(.+)(\})
```

Edit:
To further clarify, if searching through jsps, i would like to find something like the following:

```
<c:if test="${
                  !detail.hasChildList}">
```

Where the argument inside this jstl  call contains a newline.
Therefore, i need any string that starts with "${" ends with "}" and contains "\r\n".

Comment: some example input and expected output would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

In regular expressions '^' target the beginning and '$' the end.
'.' matches all elements but also new line, I would make the following regex :

```
/\${[^\n]*\n[^\n]*}/
```

Comment: I've tried this in Eclipse IDE and in Notepad++ and both complained about the statement not being valid. In eclipse when i changed your expression to: /\$\{[^\n]*\n[^\n]*}/, it stopped complaining, but didn't work.

Comment: maybe it's the encoding, try to replace \n with \n\r everywhere.
But this regex will match the strings with only one newline, for multiple newline use /\$\{([^\n\r]*[\n\r])*[^\n\r]*}/